# Magento 2.2 Code is printed in the frontend and the module isn't working

Tags: module, javascript, magento2.2

I have created a module to override a product template file (`attribute.phtml`) and JavaScript code is printed in the frontend. I have the JavaScript code inside `<script>` tags, and I have also put them inside `<head>` tags. But the code is still printed in the frontend, and so the module isn't working.

And the strange thing is, the same code and module work perfectly for another product template file (`addto.phtml`).

EDIT: THE CODE IN QUESTION

> vendor\Magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\attribute.phtml

```
<?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */

    // @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

    /**
     * Product view template
     *
     * @see \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description
     */
?>
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $_product = $block->getProduct();
    $_call = $block->getAtCall();
    $_code = $block->getAtCode();
    $_className = $block->getCssClass();
    $_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
    $_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
    $_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

    $renderLabel = true;
    // if defined as 'none' in layout, do not render
    if ($_attributeLabel == 'none') {
        $renderLabel = false;
    }

    if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
        $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getStoreLabel();
    }
    if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
        $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code)) ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code) : '';
    } else {
        $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
    }
?>
<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
    <div class="product attribute <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_className ?>">
        <?php if ($renderLabel): ?><strong class="type"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attributeLabel ?></strong><?php endif; ?>
        <div class="value" <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attributeAddAttribute ?>><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attributeValue ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
    $product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<?php if( $product->getData('size_chart') ): ?>
<?php
    $sc = $product->getData('size_chart');
    $sc = 'Mark_Sizes::documents/' . $sc . '?iframe=true';
?>
<head>
    <script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: $.mage.__('Sizes'),
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };
            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
            //$('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');
            $("#click-me").on('click',function(){
                $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<a href="#" id="click-me" class="action feature feature-icon-hover open-modal-form" title="Μεγεθολόγιο" aria-label="Μεγεθολόγιο"role="button">
    <span class="icon ib ib-hover ic ic-tshirt icon-color-productview"></span>
    <span class="label">Μεγεθολόγιο</span>
</a>

<div id="popup-modal" style="display:none;">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl($sc); ?>"/>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**And this is how is shown in the frontend.**

[image: And this is how is shown in the frontend]

Comment: Remove head tag from your code.

Comment: @SUPERDEVELOPER Working or not.

Comment: The `<head>` tag wasn't the problem. The problem persists.

Comment: Working or still problem occurred.

Comment: Not working sadly

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<head>` tag, this tag is already defined in `/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml:12` - Plus it should not be a child of body.

Comment: Well the `<head>` tag was a solution to the same problem. The problem persists without the tag

Comment: @SUPERDEVELOPER In that case it's hard to tell, there's nothing obvious in that code that could cause it so it could be another tag that isn't closed. Does your page meet HTML standards if you run it through a validator?

Comment: I only inspected it with Google dev tools and nothing showed up. I will use an HTML validator and report back with an edit.

Comment: I used [this](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fleptokaropoulos.gr%2Fpush-it-messenger-bag-eopyy) and nothing out of the ordinary/addressing my problem. It could be a tag problem, but I used the same code snippet in another template file and it worked fine. Really strange.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `<head>` tag from your code.

It is not required in your `vendor\Magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\attribute.phtml` file.

And check it.

Comment: Please don't add duplicate answers.

Answer (score 0):

The `<head>` was an approach as solving it.

In the end I solved it by enclosing all the code under the last `PHP` `if` clause inside a `div`.